# dynamic fields sorting in elasticsearch and.net

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I am trying to sort records based on dynamic field names sent to the search API. 
the d19FilterCriteria object gives me the field name(SortOn) and the order(SortOrder) for sorting. I have used a sort descriptor for this purpose.

```
   var sortDescriptor = new SortDescriptor<MPANStatus>();
   // If Field Name is Dynamic
 if (d19FilterCriteria.SortOrder == "asc")
  {
    sortDescriptor.Field(d19FilterCriteria.SortOn, Nest.SortOrder.Ascending);
  }
else if (d19FilterCriteria.SortOrder == "desc")
  {
    sortDescriptor.Field(d19FilterCriteria.SortOn, Nest.SortOrder.Descending);
  }

 var result = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<MPANStatus>(s => s
                 .Index("ampower-mpanstatusindex")
                 .Skip(skip)
                 .Size(pageSize)
                 .Sort(sort => 
                 {
                     sort = sortDescriptor;
                     return sort;
                 })
```

While debugging the sort descriptor shows me an object that has a valid value for Name and order
[image: Value of sort descriptor object while debugging]

This query returns empty list for this code. Could I know what the issue here is?

Comment: Could you share index mapping and `result.DebugInformation`?

Answer (score 0):

You can have list of sort order based on your inputs:

```
List<ISort> sdBookSortOrder = new List<ISort>();
SortOrder oSortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending;  //SortOrder.Descending;
sdBookSortOrder.Add(new FieldSort { Field = <sField1>, Order = oSortOrder });
sdBookSortOrder.Add(new FieldSort { Field = <sField2>, Order = oSortOrder });
```

And, you can use above sort order collection while sending search request - as shown below:

```
ISearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(SearchEngine.IndexName)
  {
    From = iFrom,
    Size = iSize,
    Query = query,
    Sort = oSortOrder,
  };
```

I hope, it will solve your problem.

Regards,
Nikunj

Answer (score 0):

My guess is since you are using the dynamic mapping, the string will be considered as **text field and sub field keyword**
use **field.keyword instead of just field**

Answer (score 0):

The better approach to work with dynamic sorting fields using NEST, it's using **SortDescriptor**

```
SortDescriptor<dynamic> sort = GetSorting(request.Sorting);
ISearchResponse result = elasticClient.Search<YourType>(s => s
            .Index("your-index")
            .Sort(s => sort));
```

Use this method to add a list of sorting

```
// method to generate the Sorting
public SortDescriptor<dynamic> GetSorting(List<Sort>? sorting) 
{
  SortDescriptor<dynamic> sortDescriptor = new();

  if (sorting != null)
  {
    foreach (Sort sort in sorting)
      sortDescriptor.Field(sort.Field, getOrder(sort.Order));
  }

  return sortDescriptor;
 }
```

class "Sort" just to store Field and Order values

```
public string Field { get; set; }
public string Order { get; set; }
```